# Google Sheets How to auto merge cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I'm working on a google sheets project the target is to collect some information from google form and do some data manipulation to it and hand it to the clint.

What I need to do is to find a way to automatically repeat the pattern of merging every 5 cells to gother like the one in the pic for every cell get added or making it all in advance.

if the answer include some scripting it's ok I am kinda comfortable with code. Thnx in advance.

[image]

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Comment: On  the flip side, merging is really bad practice. It changes the structure of spreadsheet that  every future calculation becomes unpredictable. Deny any merging request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to merge cells in a sheet using Google Apps Script.
- You want to merge a column every 5 cells.

In this case, how about the following sample script? From your question, I thought that when Sheets API is used, the process cost might be able to be reduced. So, in this answer, I would like to propose a sample script using Sheets API.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function myFunction() {
  const columns = [1, 2]; // These values are columns "A" and "B"
  const n = 5; //This is from your question.
  const offset = 1; // 1st row is header row.
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set sheet name.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  const maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
  const requests = [];
  columns.forEach(c => {
    for (let i = offset; i < maxRows; i += n) {
      requests.push({ mergeCells: { mergeType: "MERGE_COLUMNS", range: { sheetId, startRowIndex: i, endRowIndex: i + n, startColumnIndex: c - 1, endColumnIndex: c } } });
    }
  });
  if (requests.length == 0) return;
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ss.getId());
}
```

- When this script is run, each column of the columns "A" and "B" is merged every 5 cells.

#### Note:

- When you use only Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp), how about the following sample script?

  ```
    function myFunction() {
      const columns = [1, 2]; // These values are columns "A" and "B"
      const n = 5; // tHis is from your question.
      const offset = 1; // 1st row is header row.
      const sheetName = "Sheet1";

      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
      const maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
      columns.forEach(c => {
        for (let i = offset; i < maxRows; i += n) {
          sheet.getRange(i + 1, c, n).merge();
        }
      });
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [MergeCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#mergecellsrequest)